# Document Export failing in ms-project vba

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have code that prints specific views to pdf using a specific fromDate and ToDate.  My code started failing when I updated to ms Project 2016.  Any ideas?

I've even tried removing the FromDate and ToDate and still get the error.  When I add a watch to DocumentExport the Saveas dialog is displayed with the wrong filename, meaning the filename I am passing is not correct.

```
ViewApplyEx Name:="Gantt Employee", ApplyTo:=0 'view name

DocumentExport FileName:="C:\Schedules\test.pdf",FromDate:=printDate, ToDate:=printDateEnd
```

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Does the folder `C:\Schedules` exist already? Does your account have permission to write to it?

Comment: The folder already exists and I do have permission.  I even tried writing to the Documents folder under my profile with no success.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't work?  I'm at a loss.  Leaning towards this being a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I didn't have the latest office 365 build due to being on the semi-annual update channel.  I switched to the monthly channel updates and the problem was fixed.